# October CMS installation running on Laravel Homestead, server returning mixed up static assets

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, octobercms

I've been developing a website built on OctoberCMS, using the Laravel Homestead vagrant box as my local development server and have so far been getting along swimmingly. I developed most of a theme this way.

However I've recently started running into a problem wherein requests for assets/vendor.css in the theme assets succeed but receive a text/html response containing HTML for the homepage instead of the proper CSS.

This means vendor CSS for the page doesn't load. However if you repeat the request for vendor.css with "open in new tab" after page load the correct asset is returned, and the Chrome 'sources' tab also shows the correct asset.

This strange behaviour seems to extend to JS assets. I'm currently looking at a request for assets/vendor/jquery.js where the inital response actually contains the contents of assets/theme.css - and this is causing JS errors in the console.

In this case however if I make the request to that URL again I actually still receive the same incorrect CSS, but once again the Chrome 'sources' tab actually shows the correct asset.

Inspecting the files in my code editor I see the correct assets under the correct filenames and locations.

It seems I might have an issue with Homestead's web server. However I'm confused about where it might have come from as I haven't reconfigured anything and this has been working fine previously.

I've confirmed that the problem still persists even after deleting the homestead VM, and then building a brand new one and installing a fresh copy of OctoberCMS, without importing any of my own custom theme files.

I tried having a look into the nginx logs on the VM to see if I could spot anything odd, but it looks like they all have no content, 0 lines.

I'm a bit stumped and haven't found much helpful searching around.

Any suggestions? Help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add snapshots of what you are seeing please and the layout page code? I haven't experienced it but that would help me (us) get a better understanding.

Comment: Sure thing I'll be looking into it again today so I'll post an update soon.

Comment: So I've managed to re-build my project in such a way that this time I didn't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to re-build my project in such a way that this time I didn't reproduce the problem.

I'm pretty sure that ultimately it was caused by the fact that I relocated the homestead VM (and projects therein) by renaming its containing folder.

In previous attempts I had been deleting the VM by running `vagrant destroy` and then re-creating it by running `vagrant up`.

Once I completely deleted the homestead repository and re-cloned it from scratch from laravel/homstead on github, then proceeeded to vagrant up and set up OctoberCMS, I no longer experienced the issue.

I suspect perhaps the original path to my VM (before rename) was still in a configuration file somewhere in the laravel/homestead project and the disconnect between this value and the actual filepath was causing the problem.